# Can I read dhcp server discover message sent by others?

Tags: dhcp

when a host sends a dhcp discover message on a subnet with destination ip:255.255.255.255:67.
It is sent every host on that subnet.

Can I open port 67 on my computer
And read/respond to that message??

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can. The only prerequisites are that you have the rights to open a port in that low range. Typically linux would demand sudo privileges to open ports below 1024. And you need to be able to receive broadcast messages. DHCP clients send their DHCPDISCOVER messages as UDP broadcasts. When both prerequisites are fulfilled, then you are good to go and receive the DHCPDISCOVER messages. The response is either also a broadcast message or a unicast message, depending on the broadcast flag in the DHCP protocol packet you have received from the client host. I‘m suggesting to read the RFC 2131 protocol specification for more details.